# How does storing values in registers result in a functioning program?

Tags: assembly, x86, linux

I'm currently learning assembly, but I cannot seem to understand how storing values into registers and manipulating them results in a working program.

I was wondering if you guys could provide a very easy to understand explanation on why certain things are being done within the assembly code.

Take for example the Hello World program in assembly code:

```
section     .text
global      _start                              ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:                                         ;tell linker entry point
```

1. Why does the message length need to be put into the EDX register? And why is the EDX register chosen rather than a DX register or EAX register?

   ```
   mov     edx,len                             ;message length
   mov     ecx,msg                             ;message to write
   ```
2. I also do not understand why we are moving 1 into the EBX register? And for that matter moving 4 into the EAX register?

   ```
   mov     ebx,1                               ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov     eax,4                               ;system call number (sys_write)
   int     0x80                                ;call kernel
   ```

   Why are we moving 1 into EAX? What is so significant about EAX compared to the other registers? And what happened to the 4 stored in EAX previously?

   ```
   mov     eax,1                               ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int     0x80                                ;call kernel

   section     .data
   msg     db  'Hello, world!',0xa                 ;string
   len     equ $ - msg                             ;length of string
   ```
3. How does data in the individual register interact with each other? How do they know that data is stored within them?

TL DR: How is it all merged to present Helloworld onto the screen?

Comment: You may want to study a bit more before asking on Reverse Engineering. "How do [registers] know that data is stored within them?", for example, is an extremely naïve question. It's not as if a register must look somewhere to see if it *has* some value stored in it. The same goes, actually, for your other questions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more helpful to give a *full* sample program instead of bits and pieces. You could inline your questions using `;`-preprended lines.

> 1) Why does the message length need to be put into the EDX register?
>   And why is the EDX register chosen rather than a DX register or EAX
>   register?
>
> ```
>     mov     edx,len                             ;message length
>     mov     ecx,msg                             ;message to write
> ```

Where (in which register) each parameter lands really is a matter of the architecture (seemingly here x86_64): [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). The order usually is the same as for the C runtime functions which are the frontend to the syscalls, here [`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html). It's a convention between the kernel and user mode.

> 2) I also do not understand why we are moving 1 into the EBX register?
>   And for that matter moving 4 into the EAX register?
>
> ```
>     mov     ebx,1                               ;file descriptor (stdout)
>     mov     eax,4                               ;system call number (sys_write)
>     int     0x80                                ;call kernel
> ```

**One** is literally the file number of the [standard stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) named `stdout`.

**Four** is the system call number (essentially an index into a table) and **`int 0x80`** is a call gate into the kernel. I.e. execution transitions into the kernel and the respective system call (here `sys_write`) knows where to take the parameters from.

> Why are we moving 1 into EAX? What is so significant about EAX
>   compared to the other registers? And what happened to the 4 stored in
>   EAX previously?

Usually the return value also ends up in EAX or EDX:EAX or similar. So the 4 would have been overwritten. It depends on the return type.

**One** in this case is the system call number of `sys_exit`, the kernel-side function for the libc [`exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html) function.

> ```
>     mov     eax,1                               ;system call number (sys_exit)
>     int     0x80                                ;call kernel
>
> section     .data
>
> msg     db  'Hello, world!',0xa                 ;string
> len     equ $ - msg                             ;length of string
> ```
>
> 3) How does data in the individual register interact with each other?
>   How do they know that data is stored within them?

They don't. The kernel picks them from these registers and the (user mode) developer simply has to know where to put these pieces of data.

In the normal case the user mode developer will, however, make use of a C runtime, like glibc.

Answer (score 1):

`int 80` is used to perform system calls

Each  system call has an index

The index is always passed in **eax** register

The function calls may need arguments

The **first five arguments** are passed via **ebx,ecx,edx,esi,edi** registers

If there are more than five arguments a special method is employed using an array pointer

prototype of sys_write is as follows

ssize_t sys_write(unsigned int fd, const char * buf, size_t count)

index of sys_write  = 4

so

```
eax = index == 4,    
ebx = fd    == 1,stdout    
ecx = char* == msg   
edx = count == len
```

same goes to sys_exit

take a look at the links below for a concise syscall index ,arguments ,prototypes , and source details

http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html#note117
http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html#4

Answer (score 0):

Int 80 is a method of performing a syscall to the Linux kernel. This method is specific to Linux.

Take a look at arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h
It has documentation for this "function".

Typically in assembly you push your inputs to any function you call in reverse order to the stack. However this is a special command where the functional inputs are stored in the registers.

Take a look also at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux